# Is there any way to move a pyqt text cursor where there is no text

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

[image]I am making a text editor and now i want to want to move qtextcursor to the start of the line but the text cursor only moves from where the words start not the actual start of the line and if there is no word in the next block the cursor doesn't move there.Is there anyway around this

```
cursor.movePosition(16)
self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
#but this will only work if there is atleast one word in the next block

cursor.setPosition(0) 
#this will move the cursor to the word from where the document starts not the actual start of the document

cursor.movePosition(3)
#this will do the same
```

I am making lists function in my text editor(I am using the built-in cursor create list) but i need to modify a little and for that i have to get full control over the cursor.I have also tried using tab and backspace key spantounasly but that causes problems

Look at the image.The cursor is at the blue position.but i want it at the black one but it is currently only possible if there is text at the black position

Comment: show your code please

Comment: ok...i have done it

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have added it too.i hope its enough

Comment: still no answer